# Java, cannot reference before supertype constructor

Tags: java

I hit this case thanks to a bug (passing `name` instead of `newName` to the 2nd constructor) but curious  why the code below doesn't compile and complains about "cannot reference before supertype constructor". Thanks

```
public class Plant {
    String name;

    public Plant(){

        System.out.println("Constructor running");
    }

    public Plant(String newname ) {

        this(name, 7); //compiler error, cannot reference Plant.name before supertype constructor has been called

        System.out.println("Constructor 2 running");
    }

    public Plant(String maximax, int code){
        this.name = maximax;
        System.out.print("Constructor 3 running");
    }

    private void useName(String name){
        ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Actually you r trying here to explicitly invoking a constructor with reference to an instance field of class which is not permitted with context of this. If u want to access instance field with the context of this, you must make that field static member of class like ->

```
public class Plant {

          static String name;  // make instance field static
    public Plant(){
      System.out.println("Constructor running");
    }
    public Plant(String newname ) {
      this(name, 7); // now your code will work here
      System.out.println("Constructor 2 running");
    }
    public Plant(String maximax, int code){
      this.name = maximax;
      System.out.print("Constructor 3 running");
    }
   private void useName(String name){
       ;
   }
}
```